# open a link in a new tab in the same window

Tags: javascript, firefox, url, browser, xul

Hi I am making a firefox extension which needs to open a link in  anew tab in the same window of firefox. How should i do this?
This opens in a new window (replacing the old window):

**window.location = url;**

This opens in the same tab

**window.content.document.location = url**

Any idea on how to open the url in a new tab?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works guys! :))

```
var wm = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/appshell/window-mediator;1"] .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIWindowMediator);

var mainWindow = wm.getMostRecentWindow("navigator:browser");

mainWindow.gBrowser.selectedTab = mainWindow.gBrowser.addTab("http://google.com");
```

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried `window.open(url)`? I'm guessing opening specifically in a new tab (as opposed to a new window) is part of the browser behavior that can't be controlled via JavaScript.

Comment: this opens a new window (keeping the current window intact)
No, I think it shoule be doable using javascript coz we are able to open it in all other possible ways

Comment: hrmm okay maybe mozilla has some documentation on how to do that in firefox. sorry i cant be of more help.